# Overriding default Apex PMD rules

Tags: salesforce, apex, pmd

I'm trying to customise a PMD ruleset to identify violations of our code style conventions, for Salesforce Apex code.

Most of our conventions follow the default generally-accepted conventions in the default ruleset, but there are a few exceptions we'd like to change.

The default rules expect TitleCase for class names, and camelCase for method names and variable names. Our convention is TitleCase for both class and method names, and camelCase for variable names.

I'm new to PMD and trying to customise the default rule. I've found the MethodNamingConventions rule in the documentation here: https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_rules_apex_codestyle.html#methodnamingconventions

This provides the following example:

```
<rule ref="category/apex/codestyle.xml/MethodNamingConventions">
    <properties>
        <property name="testPattern" value="[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
        <property name="staticPattern" value="[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
        <property name="instancePattern" value="[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
    </properties>
</rule>
```

Initially straightforward, I can modify the regex to require that the first letter is capitalised, just like the rule for ClassNamingConventions.

When I realise it's possible to define different patterns for different types of method (test/static/instance) I realise I could also check for another of our conventions here, that test methods should be in the format `testCreateAccount_expectSuccessfulInsert()` - i.e. prefixed with the word 'test' and postfixed with the word '_expect' and the expected result.

I can modify the regexp for that, but doing that as part of the same rule seems to mean that it will display the same error message, defined at the rule level.

So, I assumed I could clone the rule, one 'instance' of the rule without a property for testPattern, and another 'instance' with only a property for testPattern, with a different message.

I now have the following two rules in my ruleset:

```
<rule ref="category/apex/codestyle.xml/MethodNamingConventions" message="Method names should begin with an uppercase character.">
      <priority>3</priority>
      <properties>
        <property name="staticPattern" value="[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
        <property name="instancePattern" value="[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
      </properties>
   </rule>
   <rule ref="category/apex/codestyle.xml/MethodNamingConventions" message="Test method names should begin with the word 'test' and contain the expected result">
      <priority>3</priority>
      <properties>
        <property name="testPattern" value="test[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*_expect[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*" />
      </properties>
   </rule>
```

However, when running on a non-test class (with no test methods!) , I'm now getting the error designed for test method naming!

If I look at the output of the PMD tool in VS Code, I see the following warning generated:

```
WARNING: The rule MethodNamingConventions is referenced multiple times in <ruleset_name>. Only the last rule configuration is used.
```

So clearly my concept of the rules being a hierarchy that I could override is incorrect - how should I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try making 2 files with your rules.

I have 1 file for "normal" apex, visualforce checks and 1 file for [experimental rule for detecting bad Flows](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/issues/3413). It takes forever to run and it's "just" configured to attack xml files (I don't think PMD has something for different types of XML files, it's all bundled under same language). I don't want it to examine all xmls (profiles, objects, page layouts...) so I tried to limit it to folder with flows

```xml
  <ruleset
  xmlns="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  name="Yoko Flow"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/ruleset_2_0_0.xsd">
  <description>Yoko Flow PMD ruleset, focused on performance issues</description>
  <exclude-pattern>.*/force-app/main/default/.*</exclude-pattern>
  <include-pattern>.*/force-app/main/default/flows/.*</include-pattern>

  <rule ...
```

So in your case maybe you can have 2 files, 1 for "normal" apex and visualforce running on the out of the box

`<exclude-pattern>.*/.sfdx/.*</exclude-pattern>`

and 1 only for test classes running on something like

```
<exclude-pattern>.*/force-app/main/default/.*</exclude-pattern>
<include-pattern>.*/force-app/main/default/classes/*Test.cls</include-pattern>
```